# Undoing rails generate devise views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i am starting out with rails and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and while going through the railscasts instead of doing `rails generate devise:views` i did `rails generate devise views` which is causing me a few headaches - i'd like to undo this unfortunately `$ rails destroy devise views` produces errors so i don't really know how to rollback:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant View (NameError)
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in`each'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in`to'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in `modules'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:92:in`routes'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:159:in `default_used_route'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in`initialize'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise.rb:291:in `new'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.1/lib/devise.rb:291:in`add_mapping'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-

any ideas how i can roll this back?

Comment: solved by going in and deleted the generated files manually - if there is a better way would love to hear it

Answer (score 10):

`rails destroy devise views` - convenient reversal of `generate`

Comment: This command will destroy a Devise model named "views" instead

Comment: This worked in an older version of rails about 3 years ago ;)

Answer (score 7):

the sintaxis is wrong, you just need this:

```
rails destroy devise:views
```

if you want to destroy an especific set of views use:

```
rails destroy devise:views model
```

instead of model use the name of the model you want to destroy, for example *user*, or *admin* whichever your model is.

Answer (score 6):

Just delete the `views/devise` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete "rails destroy devise views" in your routes.rb file